# ASPX vs HTML forms

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, html, forms-services

I would like to create a couple of custom new/edit forms for lists. In the past I used InfoPath but I wanted to move on to an alternative since InfoPath is going away.

This would be my first attempt in creating aspx forms in SharePoint Designer 2013, with that being said, is there any good resource/example out there in creating custom aspx forms in designer?

OR

Is it better to use Sharepoint's rest api (ajax - get/set) and create custom html forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you create Custom aspx forms for list forms. As it would be easier for you to develop and deploy the forms to the SharePoint site.

For reference how to create the Custom forms in Sharepoint designer 2013, you can follow:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23955.sharepoint-2013-building-custom-forms.aspx

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2012/09/20/how-to-create-custom-forms-using-sharepoint-designer-2013.aspx

Comment: Can we have some custom action in the aspx page!? for example I need to place a button that would open another form to upload a picture.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by InfoPath is going away? Microsoft will support InfoPath till 2023. Yes you always has the flexibility to create Visual WebParts and deploy them with SharePoint.

Using the JSOM is also not bad. If the shifting means some additional learning to you as well, then go with client side development. Because SharePoint will try its best to be a client side running product in future.

Comment: SPD creates aspx forms instead of Infopath

Comment: Yeah I was referring to the point you were saying InfoPath is going away

Comment: Yup, but your right it will still be around until 2023. Although it's not gone, sharepoint 2013 workflow does not support infopath