# List form or Infopath filtered choice column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, lookup-column, filter, list-form

I'm about to start building a custom list to capture a number of different query types.
I was intending to do this with some custom Site Content Types but I've realized that I'm going to need to filter certain choice or lookup column options based on the content type name.
Is there a simple way to do this without resorting to using InfoPath?

I'm not a developer and I'm not great at JS so OOTB solutions would be lovely.

If not I could always create 6 or 7 almost identical choice columns and use each one once in each content type but that's silly.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something like [this](http://www.uccorner.com/253/sharepoint/cascading-drop-down-sharepoint-foundation-2010/). I know you said your not great with JavaScript, but I think this is going to be your best option. I have found from personal experience that InfoPath is easy to start with, and powerful to an extent, but you will soon find its limitations and flaws. If/when that happens you will be going back and starting fresh with making custom HTML/jQuery form. That is at least where I find myself.

Edit: You may also take a look at [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114665/aspx-vs-html-forms).